# Why does math, like "while ($i < $MAX)", give "no such file or directory"?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a shell script into a file named test.sh, and the code as following:

```
echo "start"
declare -i i=1 
declare -i MAX=99999999;
while ($i < $MAX)
do
   # do something
   let ++i;
done

echo "done"
```

The result is:

```
start
test.sh: line 3: 99999999: No such file or directory
done
```

I run it on Max os Yosemite 10.10.2 and the terminal is **bash**.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: you should use [ $i -lt $MAX ]

Comment: @ShravanYadav Yes. It works. Can you post it as anwer? I will accept it.

Comment: Why downvote and close ?

Comment: I don't know. I have not done that. You can delete this question.

Comment: The biggest strike against is that it isn't currently written in a way that would help anyone else. Someone else with the same problem isn't likely to think a question named "why the shell snippet is wrong" (with someone else's snippet) will answer their problem, so they'd just ask it again. We used to have a specific close reason for that, "too localized".

Comment: If you wanted to make it a better question, you might make the title something like: Why does math, like "while ($i < $MAX)", give "no such file or directory"? -- that way, there's enough details for someone else searching the knowledge base to know if the question and its answers are applicable to their problem without needing to click through to the page.

Comment: (It's also likely duplicate -- this class of question is something of a FAQ -- but if the things it's duplicative of aren't very searchable, then it may add value by having good search terms in title and header if edited appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the problem is with ($i < $MAX) it will not work in bash. In your case it taking < as redirect operator so it is treating < $MAX as you are  giving $MAX file redirection to any loop. SO it is treating $MAX as file. That's why the error.

use

```
[ "$i" -lt "$MAX" ] ### generic POSIX number comparison syntax
```

or

```
[[ $i -lt $MAX ]] ### extended (bash/ksh/zsh) number comparison syntax
```

or

```
[[ $i < $MAX ]] ### extended string comparison syntax (may give wrong result for numbers)
```

or

```
(( i < MAX )) ### extended number comparison syntax
```

Comment: This is backwards: You need quotes in the version with `[ ]`, not the version with `[[ ]]`.

Comment: Also, the `[[ ]]` version still needs `-lt`. If you want a bash math syntax, that's `(( i < MAX ))`.

Comment: have you tested that in bash shell?? (( i < MAX )) it will work.

Comment: You need `(( $i < $MAX ))` if you want to use `<` as an operator (operate in arithmetic context).

Comment: `[[ $i < $MAX ]]` is doing string comparison not numerical comparison. That's an important distinction.

Comment: ...as using string comparison syntax will think `10 < 3` is true, because `1` is lower on the ASCII table than `3`.

Comment: @ShravanYadav, testing is hardly a good way to establish best practice. Reading the language spec is a better approach.

Comment: @ShravanYadav, ...as for why `[ $i -lt $MAX ]` is a bug, look at what it does if `MAX='1 -o -n true`. If you use `[[ ]]` or `[ ]` with quotes, then that case will be correctly seen as an error.

Comment: I agree with you all. best one is [ $i -lt $MAX ] or (( i  < MAX )) for number comparison

Comment: @ShravanYadav, ...and as for `[[ ]]` not needing quotes, that too is in the specification: It establishes a context in which both string-splitting and glob expansion are suppressed.

Comment: No, `[ $i -lt $MAX ]` is **not** best; it needs to be `[ "$i" -lt "$MAX" ]`.

Comment: ...and that's if we accept the upper-case MAX variable, which is bad practice; see fourth paragraph of the specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, speaking for best practices for naming environment variables -- keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy thanks for adding this to my knowledge.

Comment: I just made some heavy handed changes. If you don't consider them acceptable, let me know; I'll roll them back and add my own answer instead.